# SQL Text Search - EXACT before space, LIKE after in search term

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a SQL query which will supply values for auto completion for a text field.  Everything is working however I can't seem to create an SQL query which is exact enough for the purposes I want.  I am using MySQL.

If there is a space (or multiple spaces) in the search term, I only want the query to do a LIKE comparison on the part of the string after the last space.

For example, say I have two possible values in the database:

- Bolt
- Bolts Large

Currently if the user types 'Bolt' then a space, both values above are returned using this query -

```
SELECT name FROM items WHERE name LIKE 'SEARCH_TERM%'
```

What I want is that if the user types 'Bolt' then a space, then only Bolt is returned from the database.

Effectively meaning that only the last part of the search term after the space is compared using LIKE, the results should match exactly up until the last space.

I've also tried:

```
SELECT name FROM items WHERE name LIKE 'SEARCH_TERM[a-z]%'
```

But that actually returns no results using the above scenario.

Is what I'm after possible? I've also tried to explore using Full Text Search but have had no look with that. I believe full text search is enabled on the name field, however I have limited experience with this.  The query below didn't work.

```
SELECT name FROM items WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('SEARCH_TERM')
```

Any advice or points would be very appreciated.

Comment: what version of sql server?

Comment: MySQL version 5.6.21

Comment: *Both* records are returned? That must not be. It should return *no* record, as both 'Bolt' and 'Bolts Large' don't match 'Bolt %'. Are you sure? See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/623f73/1. It works as expected.

Comment: Yeah I'm sure - note my query has 'Bolt%' not 'Bolt %'

Comment: What? You said they type in Bolt and then a space. So where is the space suddenly?

Comment: Ok so there will be a space, you are correct. But it's definitely returning both results. I'm looking at the query results now.

Comment: Then LIKE is broken in your MySQL version. (Which I doubt somehow.) Have you tried the exact query `SELECT name FROM items WHERE name LIKE 'Bolt %'`, i.e. with a fix search string 'Bolt %'?

Comment: How can LIKE be broken? I've performed the query and am looking at the results.

Comment: Yes. And you certainly agree that no records must be returned for `LIKE 'Bolt %'`, because there is no matching record. But you say that two records are returned. So from what you say LIKE must be broken in your dbms. Again: Have you tried this query? Copy and paste it from my comment to make sure.

Comment: I'll perform the query in phpmyadmin and post the results as a screenshot

Comment: I am a total idiot.  Thanks for helping me pull my head out of my backside.  Of course LIKE isn't returning these results - what I believe is happening is that NSJSONSerialization in objective-c seems to be removing the trailing space from the search term - hence it's always searching for 'Bolt'.  Need to figure out how to keep the trailing space so the search performs correctly. Can't believe I missed that, thanks again.

Comment: So we found one problem :-) I'm posting an answer on how to solve the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query

```
SELECT name FROM items WHERE name LIKE 'Bolt %'
```

doesn't return any record, because both 'Bolt' and 'Bolts Large' don't match 'Bolt %'.

```
SELECT name FROM items WHERE name LIKE 'Bolt%'
```

returns both records, because both 'Bolt' and 'Bolts Large' match 'Bolt%'.

To look for 'Bolt' and not 'Bolts', you must add a space to both your search string and the column string:

```
 SELECT name FROM items WHERE concat(name, ' ') LIKE 'Bolt %'
```

returns 'Bolt' but not 'Bolts Large'.

Comment: Amazing, works perfectly.  Would you mind quickly explaining why adding a space to the column string is needed?

Comment: You are looking for the string 'Bolt '. This is no substring of 'Bolt'. You would find 'Bolt Large' and 'Bolt Small', but not 'Bolt', because there is no space after 'Bolt'. When you add a space, you also find the single 'Bolt'.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name FROM items WHERE REPLACE(name, ' ', '') LIKE 'SEARCH_TERM%'
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've this a test shortly.

Comment: Thanks for this - though should not be needed based on the comments above.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use CONCAT and TRIM, or just trim

```
SELECT name FROM items WHERE name LIKE TRIM('SEARCH_TERM')

or your choice

SELECT name FROM items WHERE name LIKE CONCAT(TRIM('SEARCH_TERM'), '%')
SELECT name FROM items WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%',TRIM('SEARCH_TERM'))
SELECT name FROM items WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%',TRIM('SEARCH_TERM'), '%')
```